# Drop rows grouped by string value - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to drop rows in a pandas df where a row is equal to a specific value. However, I want to extend this so it also drops associated rows grouped by a separate column. For instance, I want to drop all rows where `Label` == `A,D`, but I also to drop associated rows in `Num` from the same group.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({           
    'Num' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4],
    'Label' : ['X','X','A','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','D'],  
   })

df = df.groupby('Num').filter(lambda x: (x['Label'].isin['A','D']).any())
```

intended output:

```
   Num Label
3    2     Y
4    2     Y
5    3     Y
6    3     Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try use `isin` ***without*** groupby

```
out = df.loc[~df.Num.isin(df.loc[df.Label.isin(['A','D']),'Num'])]
Out[108]: 
   Num Label
3    2     Y
4    2     Y
5    3     Y
6    3     Y
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close, just add negation:

```
df.groupby('Num').filter(lambda x: ~x['Label'].isin(['A','D']).any())
```

Output:

```
   Num Label
3    2     Y
4    2     Y
5    3     Y
6    3     Y
```